# Implementing a RESTful API based Web App. Do I need a server-side framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, client-side

I'm starting a project that basically is a single-page app that downloads and shows a bunch of stats (using d3.js). The data layer is Mongo-powered, served through a RESTful API, and the client app will be coded in Ember.js. We want all data to be exchanged through the API, since we also have some mobile apps in the back burner that will hook to the same API.

I'm debating on whether write the API (using Express.js or other server-side MVC framework), or just serve the API use Deployd and not using a server-side framework at all, besides Deployd. I'll provide some hints about the project characteristics:

- The main feature is basically a dashboard that shows aggregated stats that are already computed and stored in the Mongo database.
- User interaction is minimal, enough only to allow users to customize their dashboards, but users never upload data (other that customization preferences).
- Most of the app is a lot of d3.js to create and render a bunch of graphs, which can customized in many ways.
- It requires a very rich and responsive user interface.

I proposed skipping completely the server-side framework, and simply go with a bunch of static HTML+CSS and do all the heavy lifting with a client-side MVC such as Ember.js. Since all data download and upload can be handled by Deployd, a pure static site would load much faster and is also easier to scale. Also, (I think) all user-related data and validation can be done with Deployd itself.

The thing is, some of my colleagues had a heart-stroke when I mentioned this idea. So I'd like a reality check: do I really need a server-side framework besides Deployd to cope with problems I cannot foresee yet? Are the benefits of having a pure static site a good enough tradeoff versus having, say, Express.js *just in case*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with Deployd before, but from a quick skim of its docs, it *is* a [server-side framework](http://docs.deployd.com/docs/server/). It accepts requests and respond with json. It's just oriented to APIs and json and neglects html, unlike, say, default Ruby on Rails.

The main issues I can think of that might arise due to a lack of a traditional server-side framework are things like auth, CORS, and XSS/CSRF/[other common security issues](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cheat_Sheets). You could cater for this through Deployd if it's built in or easily added, but that may be difficult.

Looking further into Deployd's docs, I see there's a [guide](http://docs.deployd.com/docs/users/) for users and [CORS](http://docs.deployd.com/docs/collections/reference/http.html#s-Cross-Origin%20Requests). I can't find anything about XSS or CSRF.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I decided to skip Deployd in favour of a more traditional Express.js API to support many of those things, like authentication using the awesome Passport, CORS, and security stuff.